# Constructing a set of numbers so that all 3 element partitions have different subset sums

Tags: algorithms, set-partition

I am interested in constructing a set of $S$ of $24$ positive integers so that any partition into $8$ $3$-element subsets, $S_1,\dots,S_8$ has the property that the sums
$$\sum_{s \in S_i} s$$
are different for every $i =1,2,\dots,8$. I would like to do this using the smallest possible maximum value of any element in the set, that is minimize $$\max_{s \in S} s.$$ I imagine that this has been studied and I simply do not know the right name for the problem.

Note that what I want is different from the "subset sum" problem which says ALL subsets of our 24 integers have different sums, although I suppose this answers the question with a (most likely) suboptimal construction.

More generally, I'm curious what is known about such sets -- for $n$ integer, how do we construct a set of $n$ positive integers such that every partition into $k$-element subsets has the property that the $k$ element subsets all have a different sum.

Comment: Must the subsets all have 3 elements? (Stated in the question, but not in the initial problem). The formulation at the end is much cleaner.

Comment: Updated, thank you @CalvinLin !

Comment: See [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A062065), smallest number such that the sums of any one, two or three of a(1), ..., a(n) are distinct (repetitions not allowed), should be a close estimate.

Comment: Thanks! I think that is just the "subset sum" number where we limit to '3-element or less' subsets? In which case, do you have a notion of how close an estimate this will be (more so for general $n,k$, but also for the 24,3 case)?

Comment: Have you tried constructing it greedily, just adding the smallest number that won't create a duplicate $2-$sum or $3$-sum?  For example, we start with $1,2,3$ and then we can't add $4$, because $1+4=3+2$, but we could add $5$, and so on.  I don't say this will necessarily give the minimum, but it will give an upper bound.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think the poor wording of the "general" form of my question has led to a slight misunderstanding. I am asking for sets of numbers which do not share a sum only for the $8$ sums obtained per partition. It seems as though @saulspatz has answered the "$3$-sum" version of the question which is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you mean to say we *can* have duplicated 2-sums but not duplicated 3-sums? Because I believe this. Looking at $\{1,2,3,5,8,10\}$ seems to exhibit this property with $\{1,10 \}$ and $\{ 3,8\}$ while if my math is right this has no partition into two 3 element sets with a duplicated sum!

Comment: I deleted that comment just before you posted yours.  Really, we can't have disjoint $3$-sets with the same sum, since we could extend them to a partition.  We can have duplicated $2$-sums, yes.  At the moment, I don't see a way to modify my script to deal with this, but it's very late here.  I'll think about it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the greedy approach I suggested in a comment, and it produced a maximum of $13796$, as opposed to the value $17404$ in the OEIS table mentioned in the comments.

I wrote this little python script:

```
from itertools import combinations

xs = [1,2,3]
twos = {3,4,5}
threes = {6}
nextX = 4
while len(xs) < 24:
    if len(xs) != 23:
        newTwos = {nextX + x for x in xs}
        if newTwos & twos:
            nextX += 1
            continue
    newThrees = {nextX + t for t in twos}
    if newThrees & threes:
        nextX += 1
        continue
    twos |= newTwos
    threes |= newThrees
    xs.append(nextX)
    nextX += 1
print(xs)

# audit
test3 = {sum(t) for t in combinations(xs,3)}
if len(test3)== 24*23*22//6:
    print('Passed audit')
else:
    print('Failed audit')
```

We start with $\{1,2,3\}$ and repeatedly try adding the smallest integer not yet tested to the set.  We keep track of all the $2$-sums and $3$-sums.  When we test a new element we accept it if its addition would not create a duplicate $2$-sum or $3$-sum.  The $2$-sum test is necessary because if there were a duplicate  $2$-sum, the addition of an further element would necessarily create a duplicate $3$-sum.  This test is unnecessary when we add the $24$th elements to the set.

The script produced the output

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 14, 25, 45, 82, 140, 235, 388, 559, 839, 1286, 1582, 2221, 3144, 4071, 5795, 6872, 9204, 11524, 13796]
Passed audit
```

Of course, there's no guarantee that the greedy algorithm produces the optimal answer.  [The greedy algorithm is guaranteed to work only when we have an underlying matroid](https://jeremykun.com/2014/08/26/when-greedy-algorithms-are-perfect-the-matroid/).  We might define a set to be independent if all of its $3$-subsets have distinct sums.  A subset of an independent set is independent, but we don't have the property that all maximal independent subsets have the same size.  $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\{1,2,3,5,8\}$ are both maximal independent subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.  So, we should call a set independent if all of its $3$-subsets have distinct sums, and all of its $2$-subsets have distinct sums.  Now it doesn't seem so easy to produce a counterexample, though if I were forced to guess, I'd say it's still not a matroid.

Even if it did turn out to be a matroid, we'd only have found the minimum for a superset of $\{1,2,3\}$, so we'd have work left to do.